# How precise is Task Manager?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, taskmanager

I have a C++ Application, when I observe Task Manager, it shows that applicaiton's memory usage increases gradually.

I manually check my source code, and I used [Visual Leak Detector for Visual C++](http://vld.codeplex.com/) to find memory leak, but I couldn't find any.
Is it 100% that there is a memory leak, and I couldn't find it or is there any possibility that Task Manager misguide me?

Comment: does the usage eventually stop increasing? Or does it go on for as long as the app is running?

Comment: Task Manager is accurate. The data it shows just doesn't mean what people often assume it to mean. That seems to be the problem in your case as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't.  It has several options for memory statistics (use View + Columns) and the version matters but the default view shows the working set.  How much of the virtual memory your program uses is actually in RAM.  That's a statistical number that can change very quickly.  Just minimize the main window of your app for example.

The VM size it can show isn't great either.  That number *includes* free heap blocks.  Getting actual memory in use is very tricky, read the small print in the SDK article for HeapWalk.

It is useless for leak detection, unless you leak gobs of it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as replacement for Task Manager. It shows history graphs for CPU/mem usage

Comment: +1 for process explorer, but you didn't actually answer OP's question

Answer (score 0):

I use Extended Task manager
http://www.warecase.com/products.asp

This is useful for debugging purpose especially to check if a thread exists or not and other such cases. It can provide lots of information if you have pdb for your process or application.

Probably you can use DevPartner for identifying memory leaks. It is very useful.