# C++ heap state difference

Tags: c++, windows, heap-memory, allocation, application-verifier

There is a big project written in C++.
Some gui action (button click) allocates 2 MB of memory. 
It is not a memory leak, course the memory is freed later. 
But I need to investigate what objects are allocated to try to reduce memory allocation size.

So I tried to use debug crt

```
OnBtnClick()
{
    //breakpoint1
    _CrtMemState s1;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint( &s1 );

        //The logic itself

    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&s1);
    _CrtMemState s2;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint( &s2 );
    _CrtMemState s3;
    if ( _CrtMemDifference( &s3, &s1, &s2) )
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics( &s3 );
    //breakpoint2
}
```

The debug report says that only 400 KB were allocated.
But process memory in task manager between 2 breakpoints increased by 2 MB.

So, created dump is useless. Can you explain me where is the rest memory allocation?

Comment: Underscore-capital names are *reserved*, making up your own in your program code makes your program ill-formed.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Unless they're [provided by the implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc28wkas.aspx); that just makes your program non-portable.

Comment: C library does not request memory allocation for each object from OS, so it probably has some unused memory "in stock".

Comment: How did you calculate your gui action to allocate 2MB? From task manager?

Comment: It could also be that the other measure is "useless". See [How precise is Task Manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467805/how-precise-is-task-manager)

Comment: I used task manager to calculate gui action. And it increases the working set by 2 MB every time gui action occurs. And after a timeout (destructor of allocated object is called on timeout) working set is reduced by 2 MB.

Comment: Is it possible that winapi allocates memory bypass runtime? So we don't see these allocations in the report.

Comment: and going step by step in the logic part of the function cannot lead you to any pointers?? i.e. call of new on the class?

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple test of creating an overloaded Global New and Delete operators that logs every request to a file. You can turn logging on/off using the state of a static global. This will give you an instrument to log each memory allocation you can expect to control.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have found out the cause of the problem.

On button click several richedit windows controls were created and filled with data.
Windows probably allocates memory bypassing runtimes. So we don't see its allocations in dbgcrt report.
But when I close richedit handles, memory is successfully released.

So, I will try to use one common richedit for all button clicks.

Thanks everyone for help!