# DirectShow Memory Leak

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, camera, directshow

I'm experiencing an important memory leak in a camera application that uses an EVR (Enhanced Video Renderer).  The leak happens when I prepare, run, stop and unprepare a graph several times (several MB every cycle, depending on the video resolution).

I simplified the code as much as I could; you can download it from here:
   https://daptech.box.com/s/6csm91vhcawiw18u42kq

The graph has a video capture filter, a SampleGrabber filter and a renderer.  When connecting, it creates an AVI Decompressor filter to complete the graph.

Here are some excerpts...

Declarations:

```
CComPtr<IGraphBuilder> pGraphBuilder;
CComPtr<IBaseFilter>   pSource;                         // The capture device filter
CComPtr<IBaseFilter>   pSampleGrabberFilter;            // Filter to capture data that flows through the graph
CComPtr<IBaseFilter>   pRenderer;                       // EVR
```

Graph preparation (validation removed):

```
hr = m_p->pGraphBuilder.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC);

hr = m_p->pSampleGrabberFilter.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC);

CComQIPtr<ISampleGrabber, &IID_ISampleGrabber> pSampleGrabber(m_p->pSampleGrabberFilter);
hr = pSampleGrabber->SetBufferSamples(FALSE);      // Don't copy image data for better performances

// Setup the callback
hr = pSampleGrabber->SetCallback(&m_p->cb, 1);         // 0: SampleCB() is called, so that we directly access the buffer.  1: BufferCB() is called.  The doc states that the function always makes a copy of the data.

CComPtr<IPin> pSampleGrabberInputPin( FindPin(m_p->pSampleGrabberFilter, PINDIR_INPUT, NULL) );
CComPtr<IPin> pSampleGrabberOutputPin( FindPin(m_p->pSampleGrabberFilter, PINDIR_OUTPUT, NULL) );

hr = m_p->pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(m_p->pSampleGrabberFilter, L"SampleGrabber");

hr = FindVideoCaptureDevice(m_p->pSource, (unsigned)iCameraIndex);

CComPtr<IPin> pSourceOutputPin( FindPin(m_p->pSource, PINDIR_OUTPUT, L"CAPTURE") );

hr = m_p->pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(m_p->pSource, L"Camera");

hr = m_p->pRenderer.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_EnhancedVideoRenderer, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC);

hr = m_p->pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(m_p->pRenderer, L"Renderer");

hr = ConfigEVR(m_p->pRenderer, m_staticPreview.m_hWnd, uWidth, uHeight);

CComPtr<IPin> pRendererInputPin( FindPin(m_p->pRenderer, PINDIR_INPUT, NULL) );

// Now select the format:
if (!SelectFormat(pSourceOutputPin, uWidth, uHeight, bCompression))
{ MessageBox(L"No appropriate format found.\n"); return; }

// Connection:
hr = m_p->pGraphBuilder->Connect(pSourceOutputPin, pSampleGrabberInputPin);
hr = m_p->pGraphBuilder->Connect(pSampleGrabberOutputPin, pRendererInputPin);
```

This function is called to "unprepare" the graph:

```
void FreeDirectShowGraph()
{
    if (pSource) DisconnectDownstream(pSource);
    RemoveAndRelease(pRenderer);
    RemoveAndRelease(pSampleGrabberFilter);
    RemoveAndRelease(pSource);
    if (pGraphBuilder) pGraphBuilder.Release();
}
```

Any clue would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you register a leak? It is not as trivial as watching task manager.

Comment: I look at the task manager, but it's so much a big leak that there's no doubt...  With the camera resolution I'm using, the leak is about 30MB everytime I switch from a camera to another one in my software.

Comment: There is no way to see a small leak on task manager. It needs to be a dramatic leak for the task manager to display it through its figures. What you see might be (and is likely to be too) a part of normal operation.

Comment: I added a button that prepares, start, stop and unprepare the graph in a loop (5 sec. per step).  After 20 minutes, it was taking 1071MB (initially it was under 50MB).  After a couple of minutes, the memory dropped to 705MB.  I'll let it "cool down" for a longer period, but it seems stable now...

Comment: Almost 2 hours have past, and the memory hasn't been released.  I'm pretty sure there's a real memory leak!

Comment: You are simply using a wrong tool: you don't see leaks with Task Manager. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467805/how-precise-is-task-manager?rq=1 and other task manager/leak related questions here on SO.

Comment: I left the program running and it eventually gave errors, having taken most of the computer's memory.