# C++ simple new & delete thread and memory leaks

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-leaks, destructor

I used threads in my code and found some memory leaks, so I tested the following simple code.

```
#include <thread>

void foo(){}

int main()
{
    for(; ;)
    {
        std::thread *th = new std::thread(foo)
        th->join();
        delete th;
    }
}
```

I tested it using VC++ Release mode without any change of settings, and I could also find memory leaks. When I checked the process using Windows Task Manager, the memory of this program was increasing.

I think the `delete` in my code doesn't work. Is there any reason why there are memory leaks?

---

More Detail

After I checked comments and the answer, I ran the program for more minutes. I could find the test program doesn't use more memory after few minutes. However I cannot sure why `thread` use more memory after `delete` (other class don't), and my program still shut down with increasing of memory usage after few minutes. In my program, only 11 `thread`s are used for each loop, so memory usage increases slowly, and suddenly shut down.

Comment: Why on earth do you `new` and `delete` the thread? Just `std::thread th(foo);`.

Comment: There are likely no leaks, but the Task Manager cannot be trusted. See [How precise is Task Manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467805/how-precise-is-task-manager)

Comment: @juanchopanza I use `new` and `delete` because I manage an unknown number of thread using `vector<thread*>`.

Comment: @D.Lucit That is no reason to use new and delete.

Comment: I test this code work fine! You should show your test result as detail.

Comment: `std::vector<std::thread>` will work fine.

Comment: @Quentin @juanchopanza  I heard that `push_back` on `vector<T>` copy the object, so I should `vector<T*>` for a performance. Is there any reason of using `thread` rather than `thread*`?

Comment: @D.Lucit `push_back` can also move the object inside the vector, but better use `vec.emplace_back(/*args*/);` to directly construct a new thread at the end of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think OS can't manage thread's memory so fast.
1) Check same code with some intervals
2) Which stats column in Windows Task Manager you look? Check "Allocated memory".

Comment: I also checked Windows Resource Manager (cannot sure it's precise), in the memory tab, and I can find same change of memory usage.